# How to select the most repeated value from each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A that contain 195*10 value, my goal is to construct a new matrix NEW that contain 195*1 values by selecting the most repeted value. there is a litle example  :

```
A=[1 5 2 1 4 1
   2 4 7 9 4 1
   9 4 7 9 9 1]
```

the result is :

```
NEW=[1
     4
     9]
```

Comment: What if a row has multiple candidates for the most repeated value? For example, what if one row contained `[2 2 2 3 3 3]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `mode` with the [dimension input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html#inputarg_dim). You will specify the second dimension meaning that you want the mode across the columns (one value for each row).

```
mode(A, 2)

%   1
%   4
%   9
```

As a note, if you have multiple values with the same frequency, `mode` will return the *smallest* of these values:

> When there are multiple values occurring equally frequently, mode returns the smallest of those values. For complex inputs, this is taken to be the first value in a sorted list of values.